# disable sortable or dragging with jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div inside a div that I don't want to be able to drag around as it is a navigation element.

example:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#container" ).sortable();
    $( "#container" ).disableSelection();
});

<div id="container">
   <div class="move">drag me around</div>
   <div class="nav">Don't move me</div>
</div>
```

Basically the .nav I don't want to be able to drag I tried this but it didn't work

```
$( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
            items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)"
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just filter out the item you don't want to be sortable:

```
$('#container').sortable({
    items: 'div:not(.nav)'
});
```

Your current filter is acting on `li` elements, you're using `div` elements.

Comment: How would you disable two elements like

$('#container').sortable({
    items: 'div:not(.nav) div:not(.nav2)'
});

Comment: it's just a jquery selector, so you'd split them by comma: `'div:not(.nav, .nav2)'`

Comment: This answer just completely saved me from doing a lot of other coding. Thanks so much.